# Is any way to set SameSiteCookie=None when remove q_session cookie on Quarkus?

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-oidc

In Quarkus OIDC, seems `q_session` can set `SameSite=None` for authentication but seems it does not effect to remove cookie.

Quarkus code:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/3.2/extensions/oidc/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/oidc/runtime/OidcUtils.java#L347C17-L347C29

```java
static void removeCookie(RoutingContext context, ServerCookie cookie, OidcTenantConfig oidcConfig) {
        if (cookie != null) {
            cookie.setValue("");
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);
            Authentication auth = oidcConfig.getAuthentication();
            setCookiePath(context, auth, cookie);
            if (auth.cookieDomain.isPresent()) {
                cookie.setDomain(auth.cookieDomain.get());
            }
        }
    }
```

My OIDC IDP supports SLO using iframe, but iframe does not set cookie if set cookie with other than `SameSite=None`, then session cookie will remain.
Is any way to set `SameSite=None` when remove cookie in Quarkus OIDC?

Quarkus version: 3.2.0.Final

Answer (score 0):

As simple solution, can set sameSite after manually logout like below:

```kotlin
    @GET
    @Path("/logout")
    fun logout(): Response {
        oidcSession?.logout()?.await()?.indefinitely()

        val cookie = routingContext?.cookieMap()?.get("q_session") as? ServerCookie
        if (cookie != null) {
            cookie.sameSite = CookieSameSite.NONE
            cookie.isSecure = true
        }

        return Response
            .status(Response.Status.FOUND)
            .location(URI("server-url/logout.html"))
            .build()
    }
```